# How to change the URL bar colour for embedded Android app web pages

Tags: android, html, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo and React Native for an Android application, and the application needs to embed web pages in certain app pages (similar to what you get when you open a link from the Gmail app). But embedded web pages within the app have either a white or black URL bar (depending on user dark mode settings), but I'd like to customise the colour.

When I add `<meta name="theme-color" content="#00f">` to the HTML pages, I manage to get Android's Chrome to display the URL bar with the custom colour:

[image]

However, when the web page is embedded inside our Android app, it doesn't affect the URL bar colour at all:

[image]

Is this something I can configure in the web pages, or would I have to configure this from Android or React Native itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same statusBar across ios/android.

Change the backgroundColor to any color.

Inside your App.tsx/jsx, change as below. E.g. white

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
<StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="white" />
```

Comment: I was actually wondering how to change an embedded mobile browser's (a browser being opened inside the app (like opening a link from Gmail)) nav bar color, not the color of the app's own status bar. So more of a HTML questions that a React Native question I guess.